# Colores en el codigo de Visual Studio Code con Python

Tags: python, vscode

Faltan algunas palabras con colores, no se si me explico, daré una imagen de prueba para demostrar.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Sin saber ni siquiera qué tema estás usando, cómo podemos saber qué falta?? Los colores vienen dados por el tema y son totalmente personalizables. Veo que afirmas que faltan colores (el blanco es un color por cierto, no es que falte uno ahí ...) pero cual es tu pregunta?? Porque supongo que tendrás una, no?

Answer (score 0):

Ahi lo logre, tuve que Instalar la extensión de Python en VSC, y darle como habilitado.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dejo prueba de lo que queria ver en el codigo, gracias por ayudar.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]